# Debugging C++ language server errors: Invalid AST

Tags: c++, emacs, ide, language-server-protocol, clangd

I've got a C++ project in which I can open up any .cpp or .h, and the LSP will crash/fail (I'm using emacs with `lsp-mode`).

For instance if I try to open a file called `IDictionary.h`, clangd will fail with the following errors in the *clangd::stderr* buffer

```
I[17:33:37.200] BeginSourceFile() failed when building AST for /home/anlsh/work/horizon-runtime/src/prod/data/IDictionary.h
I[17:33:37.246] <-- textDocument/documentHighlight(103)
I[17:33:37.246] --> reply:textDocument/documentHighlight(103) 0 ms, error: invalid AST
```

ccls also fails (exits with signal), though its error messages aren't helpful either

```
17:36:44 indexer6          indexer.cc:1302 E failed to index /home/anlsh/work/horizon-runtime/src/prod/data/IDictionary.h
/snap/ccls/48/bin/../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-7.so.1(_ZN4llvm3sys15PrintStackTraceERNS_11raw_ostreamE+0x2a)[0x7f2301010e8a]
/snap/ccls/48/bin/../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-7.so.1(_ZN4llvm3sys17RunSignalHandlersEv+0x34)[0x7f230100f544]
/snap/ccls/48/bin/../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-7.so.1(+0x907682)[0x7f230100f682]
/snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x128a0)[0x7f22fff5a8a0]
/snap/ccls/48/bin/ccls(+0x24ae87)[0x5564df56ee87]
/snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db)[0x7f22fff4f6db]
/snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7f22ffc78a3f]
```

Anyways, this happens for every single file in the project, even ones as simple as

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace Api;
```

My assumption was that some file being pulled in by the build/compile_commands.json is screwing everything up, but I can't be sure. VSCode (which I assume is using an LSP, though I know it has its own tricks) doesn't have any issues on my project at all.

Anyways, I was hoping that someone could point me towards some more detailed `clangd` or `ccls` logs, and maybe some commands which could get me some more informative error messages or validate files in my project

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be fixed on the latest versions of clangd (11.0) and ccls (0.20190823.6-26-g141aea8a)

Sam McCall over on the LLVM discord also had this to say

> You can get a bit more info by adding -log=verbose to the clangd args, and providing more of the log (things that might be relevant include version, path, preamble build, ...).
> I don't know much about windows stdafx, but I understand it pulls in a lot of stuff, some of which may have tickled a bug in that version.